# How to scrape a large table from a php website using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, scrape

I am trying to scrape the table from 'https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/mb_structure_ajax.php'.

The code I found online (rvest) did not work

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/mb_structure_ajax.php"
A <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="containerx"]/div[1]/table') %>%
  html_table()
```

A is 'list of 0'

How should I fix this code or is there any better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page source is generated by JS. Here is what you do:

1. Open the Dev Tool of the browser and go to the Network tab.
   [image]
2. Click on one of the pages and see what's going on (I clicked to page 4). You can see that the page sent a POST request to `https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/mb_structure_tableonly.php` and get the content of it.
   [image]
   Here are the parameters:
   [image]
3. Mimic the POST request by `rvest`. Here is the code to scrape all pages:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/data/mb_structure_tableonly.php"
pg <- html_session(url)
data <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    1:4288, # you might wanna change it to a small number to try first or scrape multiple times and combine data frames later, in case something happens in the middle
    function(i) {
      pg <- rvest:::request_POST(pg,
                                 url,
                                 body = list(
                                   page = i
                                 ))
      read_html(pg) %>%
        html_node("table") %>%
        html_table() 
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! So if I see there is a jsquery in network, it means the web source is generated by js.nodes?

Comment: @codingExplorer No. View the page source, not the Dev Tools (Inspect), it's the content `rvest` actually reads. If you can't find your content there, it means the content is generated by JS. Please mark my answer as answered if it does help you.

Comment: @xwhitelight, Well written answer, very nice walk through

Comment: It seems like I will have this error: ```Error: Can't combine `..1$Studies` <integer> and `..13$Studies` <character>```. after 250 pages. Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: @codingExplorer It means some of the Studies elements is not an integer but a character. Try to update the code to `read_html(pg) %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table() %>% dplyr::mutate(Studies = as.character(Studies))` and see if it's fixed.